# Syncing code across multiple computers, with minimum effort

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I would like to be able to sync source code and entire projects across multiple computers(3 to be precise). I have tried using git, but have never been able to get a hassle free experience, maybe because I've never put a lot of effort into it. So, what I want ideally is:

- Ability to add a folder with all its subfolders to the 'sync' list. Basically once I add a folder for sync, it should automatically add all files and sync them on multiple computers, just like dropbox.
- As little manual work as possible. I do not want to push multiple files and go through setup each time I create a new project.
- Version control is not one of my concerns, but is welcome.

Now, if you suggest that I use git/svn, refer to my points above so as to show my how it is useful for me. Although I don't want to spend a lot of time doing the sync part, I will if it is worth the effort.

I dont think this matters, but I use Eclipse, Aptana and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Why not just use Dropbox?

Comment: Since you cannot have arbitrary folders in dropbox, only the ones contained inside "Dropbox" folder.

Comment: As @simont suggested, if you want dropbox, use dropbox. Git can do that as well with post receive hooks. Fabric can do that in push mode if you tune your SSH keys; and you can have something like Chef or Puppet pull the code for you periodically. Or even a cron job.

Comment: I was actually thinking that there is something out there, or maybe git has some feature that I'm oblivious to. So every time you have to sync code with git, you have to do it manually?

Comment: You can make a symlink into your dropbox folder from your arbitrary folder.

Comment: There's also Sugar Sync.

Comment: you set up a chain where you push to one machine, and when it receives a push it checks it out and pushes to the next machine and so on, the order can actually be configured via a file in git. if you want it in parallel, Fabric will do the job automatically.

Comment: I am going to try out both sugarsync and sparkleshare, athough sparkleshare looks more promising(and it also has better multiplatfor support). I will try git as well, but most likely I won't go with it for now since I require sync among my own computers, and version control is not an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DirSync Pro](http://dirsyncpro.org/) might be a good solution, cross-platform and open source.

For a more bleeding edge software, you can give a try to [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/).

Finally see [this article on LifeHacker](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/03/ask-lh-how-can-i-sync-my-files-without-storing-them-online/).

Comment: I tried SparkleShare and it is definitely up to the mark. At the same time, it presents me with the same issue as dropbox. Only a particular folder is synced.

Comment: You can sync multiple folders with SparkleShare, see [Config options](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/wiki/Configuration-options)

Answer (score 1):

I had (nearly) the same situation. I ended up with a standard windows share on one (so called "master") computer  and using the shared folders as network drive with **"offline files"**.

Even if you are disconnected, you have the contents of your files available, if you are connected in same network than your "master" syncing is done automatically.

Conflicts are reported and must be resolved manually.

However, **no versioning** at all, and **windows only**.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://www.sugarsync.com

Its like dropbox but you can map any folder on one computer to any folder on another computer (or multiple computers). It's free but does not work on Linux, only Windows and Mac OS X.

Comment: Ah! almost what I was looking for, but not working on linux is a deal breaker!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check into the bi-directional synchronizer [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)

Answer (score 0):

2022 Update

- https://github.com/stephenh/mirror
- https://github.com/lsyncd/lsyncd

I am very happy with using mirror. Setup isn't too easy, but once it works, it is painless.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Google Drive.

1. Install Google Drive on all devices
2. Move the projects that you want to auto-sync to a folder in your Google Drive.
3. From your Google Drive disk on your computer, right-click on the folder in step 2, making it offline accessible

[image]