# Backup and restore libgdx projects on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

I'm having trouble to working with a libgdx project on two computers.

What is the best way to backup in one computer and then restore on another?

I use the google-play-services and BaseGameUtils and have to re-importing all time.

Comment: why dont you use GIT or any other code repository, Its worth using git makes life easy

Comment: A very nice answer is posted down

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743417/syncing-code-across-multiple-computers-with-minimum-effort refer here also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that i recommand to use Git, if it's new to you here are the main steps to get start :

1 - Create an account at [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) : you can put your code in private mode and it's free

2 - Download and Install [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) tool: it really make life easier

3 - Create your (in Server) repository in bitbucket
[image]

4-  Create your repository in Local

[image]

5 - Match between your repositories using these commands :

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin https://minos23@bitbucket.org/minos23/rep2.git
git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

**You can now pull(download)/push(upload) your code with one click !!**

Hope that was clear and helpful ! Good luck